perf trace is not available on my machine
I'm on
Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 6.8.0-45-generic x86_64)

I installed the perf packages
sudo apt install linux-tools-common linux-tools-generic linux-tools-$(uname -r)
but when I try to run perf trace it's complaining that subcommand isn't available
akhil@akhil-Inspiron-5559:~$ perf trace
perf: 'trace' is not a perf-command. See 'perf --help'.
akhil@akhil-Inspiron-5559:~$ sudo perf trace
[sudo] password for akhil:
perf: 'trace' is not a perf-command. See 'perf --help'.

however I think it is installed because when I run man perf trace I get the man page
PERF-TRACE(1)                                                                     perf Manual                                                                    PERF-TRACE(1)

NAME
       perf-trace - strace inspired tool

SYNOPSIS
       perf trace
       perf trace record

any ideas what could be happenning?
EDITS
In response to @Romeo's suggestion
akhil@akhil-Inspiron-5559:~$ perf-trace
perf-trace: command not found
akhil@akhil-Inspiron-5559:~$ sudo perf-trace
[sudo] password for akhil:
sudo: perf-trace: command not found


The trace command is no longer part of perf:
see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78878846/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-linux-cpu-scheduling-events-with-time

You are right, there is no literal 'perf trace' command in newer perf. However the functionality is still there; you can use e.g. 'perf record' to capture a tracefile of some event(s) what occurs on your system. See also 'perf list "sched:*"' for a list of static scheduler tracepoints you could tap into with perf record or other perf subcommands.

